# Is plumber's putty or tape ok?

Tags: plumbing, pool

I have a brass spigot connected to a PVC pipe near the pump of my **saltwater** pool.  There is a small leak and I was wondering if I can redo the connection using plumber's putty or tape.  Would either of these be defeated by the saltwater?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not totally sure about salt water, but I don't think it poses any special problem.  I would give the threads 2 or 3 wraps, then also coat the female threads with pipe joint cement, not plumber's putty.  Save the plumber's putty for drains and escutcheons.

Comment: I usually just use tape with PVC. I have never seen nor would recommend using plumber's putty (which, to be clear, looks kinda like play-dough) for any pressurized joint, that's what pipe joint cement (which looks more like white-out) is for.

Comment: never used PVC tape. Teflon tape is kind of the standard.

Comment: Tape did the trick.  We'll see if it holds.  I imagine Teflon is pretty non-reactive.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I use teflon tape when dealing with PVC parts.